# Saving multiple checkbox meta data WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, custom-field-type

**Code works!**

I have two custom post types: `Events` and `Artists`. I'm using WPAlchemy MetaBox PHP class , trying to create a metabox with a series of dynamically created checkboxes (i.e. there will be a checkbox for each `Artists` post) in the `Events` post editor that will allow me to select which `Artists` are appearing at an `Event`.

*Any help or insight much appreciated! Thanks!*

**This code works fine to display the checkboxes (from checkbox_meta.php):**

```
<div class="my_meta_control">

    <label>Group checkbox test #2</label><br/>

        <?php
        global $post;
        $artists = get_posts('post_type=artists');
        foreach($artists as $artist) :
        setup_postdata($artist);
        $slug = $artist->post_name;
        ?>

        <?php $mb->the_field('cb_ex2', WPALCHEMY_FIELD_HINT_CHECKBOX_MULTI); ?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $slug; ?>"<?php $mb->the_checkbox_state($slug); ?>/><?php echo $artist->post_title; ?><br/>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="save" value="Save">

</div>
```

**This code from functions.php:**

```
include_once 'assets/functions/MetaBox.php';
if (is_admin()) wp_enqueue_style('custom_meta_css', 'wp-content/themes/bam/assets/css/meta.css');

define('THEMEASSETS', STYLESHEETPATH . '/assets');

$custom_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_custom_meta',
    'title' => 'My Custom Meta',
    'types' => array('sp_events'),
    'template' => THEMEASSETS . '/functions/checkbox_meta.php'
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed a helper class which might help you with [creating wordpress meta boxes](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/).

Comment: thanks alot dimas! Actually just checked out your site a few hours ago from a recommendation from a friend-- looks very promising!

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the problem

```
$data = stripslashes_deep($_POST['artist']);
```

Try to change it to

```
$data = stripslashes_deep($_POST);
```